# How can I speed up "Joining" two collections

Tags: arangodb

I have two collections. Let's call them `cars` and `accidents`. There are a lot of documents in `cars` (millions) and relatively few in `accidents` (hundreds to thousands).

`cars` and `accidents` are connected via an edge `car_accidents`. For `cars` I have a view (`carSearchView`) to apply certain `analyzers`.

If I now query for `cars` together with `accidents`, the query is extremely slow (>1min for 10 million `cars` and 300 `accidents`):

```
FOR car IN carSearchView
  SEARCH (car.color=="blue") AND (car.registrationDate < 1693292292000000)
  FOR accident, edge IN 1..1 INBOUND car car_accidents
    FILTER (accident.hasDamageToPerson)
  COLLECT distinct_car = car
  SORT distinct_car.registrationDate DESC
  LIMIT 0, 100
  RETURN distinct_car
```

The `SEARCH` and `FILTER` strings are just an example. There is a bunch of properties the user can filter/search for (both in `cars` and `accidents`).

I don't want to store all the `accident` data with the `car`, since more than one `car` can be involved in the `accident` and it would make updating `accident`-data really cumbersome, error-prone and non-atomic.

How can I speed up this query? Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I use ArangoDB?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html#indexing-complex-json-documents and see if adding indexes/reverse indexes where applicable does the trick.